# unable to click on input box in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

The chat system is working fine on all browsers(desktop) but buggy on phones due to 2 reasons:

I am using position:fixed and when a button is clicked, a div slides up and the chatbox is opened.

- position fixed is working very unpredictably in phones. I've gone through many workarounds for this,but nothing seems to fit my purpose. What I need is a div to slide up when a button is clicked.
- I am unable to click on the input button on the chatbox, while the other smilies and submit button works fine.

Here's css and js code which I am using:

originaly(and on close button click):

```
$("#chatarea").animate({"bottom":"-600px"});
```

on click:

```
$("#chatarea").animate({"bottom":"0px"});
```

I've set the textbox CSS to:

```
z-index:101;
```

still all other smilies work fine without even specifying z-index.

I am unable to post complete code as it is mixed up in php echo's. Input autofocus is working correctly but I need to be able to click to enter text. Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem with android devices.